# Google map business search

Tags: asp.net, html, google-maps-api-3, html-helper

i'm building a website for a client and he wants a search function so you can view all poker venues in the UK, I thought this would be pretty simple as it is all situated around a google map search, well I'm struggling.

Basically, I'm after something that looks the same as this;

http://www.redtoothpoker.com/league.asp

Any ideas where I could start?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We really can't help you with a question such as this. We're more here to help you with specific programming issues you are having - not for 'brainstorming' or general research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps are javascript library that you include in any page, now you have the simple search that you can include from google.

You can do it from here: http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http%3A//www.gstatic.com/ig/modules/mapsearch/localsearch_v2.xml&pt=%26context%3Dd%26type%3Dgadgets%26synd%3Dig%26lang%3Den%26.lang%3Den%26country%3Dnl%26.country%3Dnl%26start%3D0%26num%3D1%26target%3DytxS%26objs%3D&sn=&lang=en

And Emble the code in your page.

And you have the more complicated part, this one if you have your own data in your database and you want to make your custom queries.

As i saw you have .asp page so i asume your using asp with MSSQL, first you need to make your data structure and search queries in this structure, when a client comes to ur site and search then you will have to make a call via ajax to the Database retrieve all the "Poker places" keep in mind you need the address of those places, set them in Javascript and push them to the map.

Best place to start is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Google map requires basic knowledge of html and javascript.

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: That isn't actually my page, thanks for the help though guys :L This is going to be harder than I thought.

Comment: If you need help i can give a hand :)

Comment: Fantastic, how can I contact you?

Comment: you can find my blog on my profile contact me there and ill try to help.

Comment: Thank you so much, just messaged you now!